# Why does the Receive.dll in Biztalk 2020, wrap my xml message in a string element with a xmlns?

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk

I am using HTTP Handlers with Receive.dll on IIS. When the website sends a message for example:

```
<ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/MainData">
<ns0:Columns>LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID</ns0:Columns>
  <ns0:Query></ns0:Query>
</ns0:Select>
```

it gets wrapped with a string element like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
&lt;ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/MainData"&gt;&lt;ns0:Columns&gt;LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID&lt;/ns0:Columns&gt;&lt;ns0:Query&gt;&lt;/ns0:Query&gt;&lt;/ns0:Select&gt;
</string>
```

When it hits the orchestration it fails to find the Select schema. I tried using a pass through on the Receive shape and remove the `<string>` element in a construct using an external class and re-assigning the message with the new value, but still fails. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Did you configure any verbs (GET, DELETE) on the Incoming Message on your Receive Location? Do you have a Receive Pipeline other than XmlReceive configured on your Receive Location?

Comment: verbs POST. No other pipelines. I should not need a custom pipeline, I would think if it was needed it would be mentioned in the document.

Comment: Just to be clear: Not the **HTTP Method** on the *General* config tab but the **Add Message body for verbs** on the *Messages* tab.

Comment: In BizTalkServer?

Comment: Yes, on the according HTTP Receive Location.

Comment: HTTP Receive Location configure has only one table and no place for verbs, that should be set on IIS, which I set up the POST verb.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about the ***Receive Port*** - I was referring to the ***Receive Location*** referenced inside your Port.

Comment: So am I. open up biztalk and a receive location and you'll see what I mean